# Disabling Amazon Payments Advanced method from WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm trying to disable a couple of payment gateways based on a user's role. The function & hook I found works on the Paypal method but not Amazon Payments Advanced. Here's my code:

```
function wk_disable_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $wholesale_cust = check_user_role( array( 'wholesale', 'orig-wholesale' ) );
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && $wholesale_cust ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['amazon_payments_advanced'] ) && $wholesale_cust ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['amazon_payments_advanced'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'wk_disable_gateways' );
```

The "Pay with Amazon" code is still running on the checkout page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best solution, but I have not been able to find a more viable answer.

First off I did what you did and disabled all gateways expect the one I wanted the user to use. In my case I only want someone to check out with the nmigateway.

This goes inside of your theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);

function filter_gateways( $gateways ){

  global $woocommerce;

    // what products you wish to exculde 
    $nonPPproducts = array(1457, 1447, 479); // LIST YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {

        if ( in_array( $values['product_id'], $nonPPproducts ) ) {  
            foreach ( $gateways as $gateway_key => $gateway ) {
                if ( $gateway_key !== 'nmipay' ) {
                    unset( $gateways[ $gateway_key ] );
                }   
            }
        }

    }

  return $gateways;

}
```

Next here is the part that makes this not the best solution editing the plugins source code.

Change the following two functions inside of the plugins/woocommerce-gateway-amazon-payments-advanced/amazon-payments-advanced.php

```
/**
 *  Checkout Button
 *
 *  Triggered from the 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' action.
 */
function checkout_button() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // what products you wish to exculde 
    $nonPPproducts = array(1457, 1447, 479); // LIST YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        if ( in_array( $values['product_id'], $nonPPproducts ) ) {  
            $disable_button = true;     
        }
    }
    if(!isset($disable_button) && $disable_button !== true ){
        ?><div id="pay_with_amazon"></div><?php
    }
}

/**
 *  Checkout Message
 */
function checkout_message() {
    global $woocommerce;
    // what products you wish to exculde 
    $nonPPproducts = array(1457, 1447, 479); // LIST YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        if ( in_array( $values['product_id'], $nonPPproducts ) ) {  
            $disable_button = true;     
        }
    }
    if(!isset($disable_button) && $disable_button !== true ){
        if ( empty( $this->reference_id ) ) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-info info"><div id="pay_with_amazon"></div> ' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_amazon_pa_checkout_message', __( 'Have an Amazon account?', 'woocommerce-gateway-amazon-payments-advanced' ) ) . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that when the plugin is updated all of your changes will be lost.